# C# Serial Port Auto closes

Tags: c#, serial-port

Im trying to read data from a COM  serial port, but the port is auto closing randomly, i dont know what to do, nowhere in my code i call the close method. i tried setup events on dispose, setup try catch and debug all catchs, but no luck.

Tried to create an infinity thread that when SerialPort.isOpen return false the thread reopen the serial port, it work but the thread eats the cpu at 100%..

Dont know what else to do...

The code that opens the serial

```
_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(RecebendoDados);
_serialPort.Disposed += new EventHandler(PortaFechou);
_serialPort.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(PortaErro);
_serialPort.PinChanged += new SerialPinChangedEventHandler(PinMudou);                
_serialPort.Open();
PortIsOpen = _serialPort.IsOpen;
```

Comment: Does the Serial port object throw an event to notify when it closes? If so, your reopen thread could just wait, and be notified when the close occurs.

Comment: Make sure you disable hardware controls.  They are archaic and can give issues especially if your cable has them attached.  I also have seen issues with USB/9 pin D-Connectors adapters have this type of behavior when wired incorrectly.

Comment: For Mark, the port object in the documentation said that it throws an event when the COM port dispose(after closing), but i tried to monitor this event and  it dont fire up, its never raised.

Comment: For jdweng, i'm using one of this adapters (usb/9pinD) that i bought, but since i don't have a serial port on my laptop its hard to test and figure out, i'll try something else using a pc and a PCI COM port. Also can you explain this "disable hardware controls"? disable where?

Comment: It is unlikely the port is auto closing.  Your other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458979/c-sharp-randomly-stop-receiving-data-in-serial-port mentions an ObjectDisposedException.
Seems possible the garbage collector is disposing your port for you.
As an experiment, try using GC.KeepAlive() to maintain a reference to your Serial Port.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you keep the COM port opened? Just open it when you write then close it!
Use this:

```
    if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
        serialPort1.Open();
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        serialPort1.WriteLine(inst.ToString());
        serialPort1.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I keep it open because the device send continous  information ,  i dont even write anything,  just listen to data sent,  and its a lot of information,  one of them its a stopwatch  that increments  and send data ( from the device to the pc) ..  So  i need to keep it open all the time  to not lose anything

Comment: @EduardoEstevão, you tried `serialPort1.ReadTimeout = SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout;`, right?

Comment: No,  i tried a really  Big number,  but didnt  seen  this option,  ill look into it, Thanks

Comment: Still the same thing

Comment: @EduardoEstevão, the thread that check `if (!_serialPort.IsOpen;)` you should put it to sleep for a time (the expected time for the port to stay opened). This will make the thread take less CPU usage.

Comment: i dont know if helps but it seems to be outputing this data when the port closes. "The thread 0x2e84 has exited with code 0 (0x0)."

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
I discovered that the different threads got messed up (my fault).
This caused `_serialPort.Open()` to be called again, while the port was still open.
Since I had some exception handlers to catch disconnections, the `Open()` method was a called over and over again.
So when this happens:

1. Disable all exception handlers
2. Review your code or step through your code to understand why `Open()` method is called  while the port is already open